# as the code is correct i am still getting syntax error due to unknown reason?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This the problem which is mostly shown by VS Code or it may sometimes shows that the `import` statement cannot be used out of the module.

That is an ES6 problem that can be solved in 2 ways: one by adding type as a module in `package.json` and other by saving the file by name of `app.mjs`. After that, it shows this syntax error by both methods after solving the problem in which we can not use the import statement out of the module.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18) 
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:483:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:21)
```

I  have been using this code:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Row from './Row';
import requests from './requests';
import Banner from './Banner.js';
import Nav from './Nav';
```

Here starts the function code

```
function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
    <Nav />
            <Banner />
            <Row title="NETFLIX ORIGINALS" isLargeRow fetchUrl={requests.fetchNetflixOriginals} />
            <Row title="Trending" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTrending} />
            <Row title="Top Rated" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTopRated} />
            <Row title="Action Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchActionMovies} />
            <Row title="Comedy Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchComedyMovies} />
            <Row title="Horror Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchHorrorMovies} />
            <Row title="Romance Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchRomanceMovies} />
            <Row title="Documentaries" fetchUrl={requests.fetchDocumentaries} />
    
  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check node version and make sure you are using 14+ which allows modules.

```
node --version
```

If it is under 14 upgrade to lts v16 version.

Comment: Actually, its the latest version 18.7.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What engine did you use to start your project? CRA? Custom?
What is this property "fetchUrl"?
I would suggest that you comment out each item from your app's return statement and see if you can identify which one is throwing the error.

Comment: usually, I use the vs code's terminal to start my project. And as you said to comment on each item from your app's return statement .Ya I will try my best.